# Как вывести долю по условию sql

Tags: sql

Есть таблица вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести долю client_id, у которых man_status = 'Active'

Comment: `SUM(man_status = 'Active') / COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select sum(case when man_status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) from table_name
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]